# Hadoop - Average shuffle time too long

Tags: hadoop, shuffle, hadoop-streaming

I need a suggestion ...

We see a very high average shuffle time ... how can it be optimized?
(we use hadoop streaming on AWS EMR)

[image]

Comment: Is mapper doing anything other than emitting key-value pair (its quite fast)? Any processing on key or value or anything else? Whats the step prior to this in your data pipeline?

Comment: Of course it does ... some filtering. There's no step prior to this.